# Convert value columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
     A     B       C
0  mel  0.00    3.99
1  sid  7.23   13.30
2  alc  0.00    2.14
3  fas  8.12  108.00
```

I want to convert 0.00 values in their respective *C column* values.

The output must be:

```
     A     B       C
0  mel  3.99    3.99
1  sid  7.23   13.30
2  alc  2.14    2.14
3  fas  8.12  108.00
```

I´ve tried:

```
df.replace(["0.00"], ["C"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

Get the indexes of the rows you want to fill. Then replace those values:

```
idx = df["B"] == 0
df.loc[idx, "B"] = df.loc[idx, "C"]
print(df)
#     A     B       C
#0  mel  3.99    3.99
#1  sid  7.23   13.30
#2  alc  2.14    2.14
#3  fas  8.12  108.00
```

You could do this as a one-liner, but I put I wrote it like this for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

`replace`+ `bfill`

```
df.replace(0,np.nan).bfill(1)
Out[2049]: 
     A     B     C
0  mel  3.99  3.99
1  sid  7.23  13.3
2  alc  2.14  2.14
3  fas  8.12   108
```

Or

```
df.loc[df.B==0,'B']=df.C
df
Out[2052]: 
     A     B       C
0  mel  3.99    3.99
1  sid  7.23   13.30
2  alc  2.14    2.14
3  fas  8.12  108.00
```

Comment: Or even: `df.B.where(df.B != 0, df.C, inplace=True)`

Comment: @JonClements yep, and maybe ,mask and np.where also work for this :-)

Comment: something about felines and skinning and many ways and all that :)

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
df.loc[df['B'].eq(0), 'B'] = df['C']
```

Result:

```
     A     B       C
0  mel  3.99    3.99
1  sid  7.23   13.30
2  alc  2.14    2.14
3  fas  8.12  108.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one liner:

```
df['D'] = df.C.combine_first(df.B)
```